# Emacs - selection not showing in windowed mode

Tags: emacs

I have Emacs on a Kubuntu 15.04 OS and I have a problem in showing the selected region; if I run emacs in the terminal windows with -nw option, I can set marks and I see the selected region highlighted; but if emacs starts in a window, the selected region is not highlighted, though it is still selected (ctrl+w cuts that part). Note that transient-mark-mode doesn't affect this behaviour, whether it is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to [Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729907/drew) I finally managed to resolve this issue!

I had a file with path: `/etc/X11/Xresources/x11-common`

With the following content:

```
! $Id$

! load color-specific resources for clients that have them
#ifdef COLOR
*customization: -color
#endif

! make Xaw (Athena widget set) clients understand the delete key
! this causes problems with some non-Xaw apps, use with care
! *Text.translations: #override ~Shift ~Meta <Key>Delete: delete-next-character()
```

What I just did was moving that file away, running `xrdb` with an empty input, and everything went fine!

Now I just need to figure out what the content of that file was and what to do if I need to put it back where it was.

Thanks a lot for your precious help, Drew!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this behavior when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (i.e., without an init file)?  If not, then recursively bisect your init file until you locate the culprit code.  You can do use command `comment-region` to comment out the region (with `C-u` it uncomments). Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... until you find the culprit.

- If you see a problem using `emacs -Q` then give a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it.
- If not, and if you narrow your init file to locate the problem but you still need more help at that point, report as much as you have found out, specifically.  Again, step-by-step specifics help.

Comment: The behavior I'm getting it's kinda strange.. with emacs -Q everything works fine, but if I launch it without that option and with a completely commented init file I experience the same problem.

There is't really a step-by-step recipe at this point: even with a completely commented init file, if I launch emacs -nw selection works fine, if I launch it   regularly (in a windows) selection is not highlighted.

Comment: Sounds like the difference between `emacs -q` and `emacs -Q`. Test to see. If so then the problem is likely in some other initialization file (e.g., `default.el`, `site-lisp.el`, `site-start.el`) that is getting loaded. See the Emacs manual, nodes [Init File](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), [Initial Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html), and [Entering Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Entering-Emacs.html).

Comment: Ok i think I narrowed it down. It works indeed with `emacs -Q` but not with `emacs -q`.

That said, the problem seems to be not related to the other files: I don't have any of them, and manually invoking emacs with `--no-init-file --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --no-splash` doesn't resolve the issue. So i guess the problem is related with this part from the manual:

_This also stops Emacs from processing X resources by setting inhibit-x-resources to t_

But that variable seems not to exist and trying to setting it to t in the init file doesn't change the behavior I get

Comment: Are you on a platform (e.g. Linux, UNIX) that allows use of X resources? If so, are you using X resources? If so, try to figure out what the problem might be with them - same thing: binary search (bisect recursively). And consider sending an Emacs bug report (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) for the problem of the doc seeming to be inaccurate/incomplete wrt variable `inhibit-x-resources`.